# Execute a python script stored on a web server using beautiful soup

Tags: python, cgi, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a simple form/script combination that will allow someone to replace the contents of a certain div in an html file with the text they input in an html form on a separate page.

The script works fine if everything is local : the script is local, i set the working directory to where my html file is, and i pass the parameter myself when I run the script. When I load everything to my hosted site server, however, it gives me a 500 error.

I have been able to execute a simple python script that i stored on my site, and JustHost, my hosting service, has told me that BeuatifulSoup has been added to my server.

Here is the script, with the parameter "textcontent" coming from an html form which works fine. My scirpt is rooted  under public_html/cgi-bin/ and the html I am trying to read and write resides on the root of public_html. I'm guessing either the html file isn't being found or beautifulsoup isn't actually available on my server...anyway way to test that??

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import beautifulsoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb, traceback


# Create instance of FieldStorage 
try:
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()    
    def text_replace(word):
    f = open('/public_html/souptest2.html', 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
    f.close()

    text = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'sampletext'}).string
    text.replaceWith(word)

    deploy_html = open('/public_html/souptest2.html', 'w')
    deploy_html.write(str(soup))
    deploy_html.close()

# Get data from fields
    if form.getvalue('textcontent'):
        text_content = form.getvalue('textcontent')
        text_replace(text_content)
    else:
        text_content = "Not entered"
except:
    deploy_html = open('../souptest2.html', 'w')
    traceback.print_exc(deploy_html)
    deploy_html.close()
```

I have tried to load that as a script and run it from a url and still get a 500 error, with no output on my output page in order to debug using traceback...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize I needed to demarcate my code snippet...

Comment: Check the server logs; if you haven't actually installed BeautifulSoup there, it's probably likely the 500 is caused by an ImportError, but it's entirely possible something else is going wrong there.

Comment: @Wooble - The logs aren't very specific. It says the file doesn't exist.  What else could be going wrong if the script runs fine locally?

Comment: What file does it say is missing?

Comment: @benson - File does not exist: /home/simondo1/public_html/404.shtml

Comment: That's indicating the 404 error page doesn't exist, isn't it?  That looks like an unrelated error to me.  Is there another error above that in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a shell account on your host? If so, try running the server's version of Python in interactive mode and type:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
```

If the module doesn't exist, you should get an `ImportError`.

Alternatively, try putting `cgitb.enable()` immediately following the line `import cgi, cgitb`. This *should* give you the traceback of any exceptions raised. If this *still* doesn't work, it's likely that your webserver isn't finding the script. Double-check your configuration with your hosting provider.

There is a whole bunch of advice on how to debug CGI scripts in Python's CGI documentation, found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html).

**EDIT**: Edited to actually take advantage of the `cgitb` module rather than try to handroll a solution using `traceback`.

Comment: I have tried the cgitb.enable(), and it opens a blank html page, with no error or anything. I'm wondering if my problem is with the path I have set for the html file that resides on my server...I have tried it both as "/public_html/souptest2.html" and also as "../souptest2.html" are there any other options I should try?

Comment: here's the script's url with the parameter "textcontent" posted manually as test. It gives me a blank html page. weird : http://simondoty.com/cgi-bin/replace_html.py?textcontent=test

Comment: Since this works locally, the problem is almost certainly in your setup on the server. Does a small "hello world" type script without BeautifulSoup work?

Answer (score 0):

To test do something like:

```
try:
  from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except Exception, e:
  print "An error occured importing soup", e
```

You need to fix the output, such that you would actually see it, or alternatively write something to a file.